# Who saved "Scrapper 142"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, we saw that

> Scrapper 142 was actually a Valkyrie who was earlier saved by another Valkyrie from Hela. In the movie it happens in the bit between Hela throws a sword and Scrapper (as a Valkyrie) falls [image]

From

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valkyrie_(Marvel_Comics)#In_other_media

> Tessa Thompson appears as [a] Valkyrie in Thor: Ragnarok.

---

> There, the entire Valkyrie force was wiped out by Hela when Odin sent them to stop her. The only survivor is seen in a flashback being ***saved by a fellow warrior who took a spear for her.***

My question: Is the Valkyrie that takes a spear the Valkyrie Brunnhilde ?

> Because she is blond and Scrapper is brunette
>  [image: Blond Valkyrie]

I have not followed the Marvel universe well enough to know.

She did look the part - I do not have a screen cap though

[image]

Comment: Sure. Why not? She could be anyone you want, I think.

Comment: @JDoe - But IS she?

Comment: For the record Brunhilde *is* Valkyrie AKA Scrapper 142 (AKA Tessa Thompson)

Comment: @Valorum So she will become blond?

Comment: @mplungjan - She wouldn't necessarily become blonde. Just as in the comics Heimdall has nowhere near such a dark complexion as has been seen in the MCU it is all about casting...

Comment: Still as a Dane I had a hard time imagining a brunette - just like it took me a bit of time to get used to a deeply tanned Heimdall next to a stereotypical Thor :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TLDR**

- Tessa Thompson is Scrapper 142 (Just in case you didn't look that up...)
- I have attached picture of the valkyrie  in question and a couple shots of the cast list (Don't tell Disney...)
- Given the character names in credits she is likely just a throw away character...
- I am 99% sure valkyrie in question is Valkyrie Sister #2 - Samantha Hopper

So using my secret sources I was able to get a picture of both the valkyrie in question and a couple shots of the cast list (sorry about the poor resolution). This is also the best shot we get of her face from the movie. She is only in three shots. Listed in the cast credits Valkyrie Sister #2 is Samantha Hopper. If however this is not her she is not listed in the credits from what I can tell.

[image: cast shot 1]
[image: cast shot 2]
[image: from the movie]
[image: from her twitter]

Answer (score -4):

## Beerbot 5000, or possibly Valkyrie Sister #1, or Valkyrie Sister #2

The [IMDB credits page for Thor: Ragnarok](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3501632/fullcredits/) lists each of the roles played by actors in the film, whether they are named or not. Each of the named characters except for Beerbot 5000 can be accounted for. Of the unnamed characters, only the titles "Valkyrie Sister #1" and "Valkyrie Sister #2" make any sense. So most likely the character is Beerbot 5000. But seeing as the character is dressed as a Valkyrie with nothing in particular to make her stand out, there is no reason to think that she could not simply be Valkyrie #1 or Valkyrie #2. There is nothing to suggest that she is any named Valkyrie or other character.

Comment: Looks like Samantha Hopper could be it if I remember right... Here is the Wikipedia version of Brunnhilde https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ad/Valkyrie_Secret_Avengers_Vol_1_14.png

Comment: The less than perfect IMDB also lists [Hamish Parkinson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3312641/) as portraying Beerbot 5000, so not likely to be that.

Comment: What, exactly, makes you think the *Valkyrie* whose *name we don't know* is "most likely" the character **Beerbot 5000** and not one of the unnamed Valkyries?

Comment: I'm guessing this is beerbot 5000; https://static.cinesearch.com/assets/images/us/thor-ragnarok/gallery_thumb_1376c7388daf9b3d24dd94dc08c1f8ac79b4cb48.jpg